# make jquery ui dialog on the top of cytoscape network

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js

I have problems to move the dialog around the cytoscape networks,see my graph(
    http://raven.anr.udel.edu/~sunliang/biolayout1/biolayout2.php?fileName=usrID/id_1378869568_41_gene_iterm.txt

),click menu 'Diagram', if the dialog is moved on the top of cytoscape network, I can not close or drag it anymore, I know it's something related to overlaying. It seems dialog box is hidden under the cytoscape network. Is there any way to make the dialog above the network, So I can drag them, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the dialogue is outside the cy div, and make sure its css is set properly (z-index, etc). -M